# Ubuntu Server 20.04 change screen resolution

Tags: boot, grub2, display, display-resolution

I am struggling to change the console resolution to something lower than 4k as it is too small but I cannot do it.
I tried editing:
/etc/default/grub
and adding:
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

and then running:

update-grub

But the result is initial boot is in 1024x768 and then in the process of booting is's switching back to 4k. I think it's starting with the console but then it's switching to the framebuffer.
Can someone help with changing the resolution fromm 4k to maybe something like full HD?

Please note: this is not Ubuntu Desktop, there is no X Server or GUI installed.

Comment: Can you identify any installed graphics driver, that is (in the booting process) loaded as a kernel module?

Comment: I don't think so. This is a fresh install. I haven't added any driver.

Comment: [    0.964049] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
[    0.964109] efifb: probing for efifb
[    0.964122] efifb: framebuffer at 0x4000000000, using 32400k, total 32400k
[    0.964124] efifb: mode is 3840x2160x32, linelength=15360, pages=1
[    0.964126] efifb: scrolling: redraw
[    0.964128] efifb: Truecolor: size=8:8:8:8, shift=24:16:8:0
[    0.964206] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.977129] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device

Answer (score 3):

I tried to change the resolution, but it didn't work. Later, I changed the font size, which can be displayed well at 4K resolution.

sudo vi /etc/default/console-setup

edit content: FONTSIZE="16x32"

save and exit （:wq)

reboot

Comment: good solution.  worked well on asus chromebox UEFI boot with 4k monitor for ubuntu server 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was found, apparently, in some Raspberry Pi forums. After all the Intel NUC is just a more powerful RPi.
I have added:

> video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@60

as a parameter to the kernel.